# How to Create PayPal App Id live credentials for pro account

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to create app id with pro account.I have integrated paypal Getvarified status api  with sandbox APP Id .Its working fine.For integrate that api i need live app id ,I am using LIVE REST API STEPS from following link:

http://geekmechanics.weebly.com/paypal-rest

then api code display the app id wrong error.

I am stucked here from last 3 days .Anyone can help me please.Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Rest APP id is different from Adaptive APP id. Getverified status API needs Adaptive APP ID. Please refer the following link:https://www.paypal-apps.com/user/my-account/applications. Sign into your PayPal account and submit the application. For PayPal support refer the following link: https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask.